# shutil copy tree error

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error says \\\\Ref\\builds/out exists but it doesnt exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176227/error-says-ref-builds-out-exists-but-it-doesnt-exist)

I am trying to copy a source code tree using the below code and running into this error,am not sure why I am getting this?error says \\Ref\builds/out exists but it doesnt exist,any one has anyinputs on what is wrong here?

```
//local/mnt/workspace/04.01_HY11/out
\\Ref\builds/out
copying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 18, in main
    copytree(src,dst)
  File "test.py", line 11, in copytree
    shutil.copytree(s, d)
  File "/pkg/qct/software/python/2.5.2/.amd64_linux26/lib/python2.5/shutil.py", line 110, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "/pkg/qct/software/python/2.5.2/.amd64_linux26/lib/python2.5/os.py", line 171, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '\\\\Ref\\builds/out'
```

Python code

```
import os,shutil

def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        print s
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        print d
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            print "copying"
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
def main ():
    src="//local/mnt/workspace/04.01_HY11"
    dst="\\\\Ref\\builds"
    copytree(src,dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: @loreb - yes,destination should be copied to \\Ref\builds ,this is a different location on the network,am trying to copy the source tree from local to a different location on the network...is this not right?

Comment: Do you realize that "\b" is an escape character?

Comment: @SteveMayne - i realized that and updated the question,how do I resolve the original error?

Comment: @ all - i updated code and the recent error

Comment: @user1927396 FYI seeing stack trace you use 2.5.2, not 2.6.5. Using extra arguments will lead to error.

Comment: Please don't repeat the same question. If you don't get helpful answers, try to improve the question by giving more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because destination directory already exists, you must remove it before.

Comment: It actually doesnt exist but the error says it exists..thats where I am getting confused